# Interior of lighthouses in Shutter Island and The Lighthouse

Tags: film-location, shutter-island, set-design, the-lighthouse

In Shutter Island (2010) there is a lighthouse. Although [the location of the exterior is explained in standard movie location websites](https://www.movie-locations.com/movies/s/Shutter-Island.php), I could not find an explanation for the interior having an elaborate wrought iron spiral staircase. I ask because this staircase seems to be very similar to the staircase in another movie, The Lighthouse (2019), starring William Dafoe. However, my understanding is that the lighthouse in that movie was constructed especially for it.

So, is the resemblance between the staircases coincidental or are they connected in some way?

Comment: Apart from it being a lighthouse and even if the set is made for movie it have some resemblance in reality? https://brightlightsfilm.com/to-the-lighthouse-cinematic-lighthouses-in-shutter-island-annihilation-and-the-lighthouse/#.XoL22nduLcs

Comment: Aren't the lighthouses supposed to share a common design since the have only one purpose ?

Comment: @Rahul The staircase in both movies is very similar

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the image gallery when searching "Lighthouse Interior", there are many which share the same staircase feature.

https://www.google.com/search?q=lighthouse+interior&rlz=1C1AOHY_enUS821US821&sxsrf=ALeKk03Zlk4CcMftzYhjJ21bWejIYcs61A:1585662024452&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix1M2t68ToAhVqkuAKHWz4A9QQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1198&bih=867

[image]

There are others which aren't exact matches, but are similar in design.

[image]

Comment: Neither of the pictures you linked matches the staircases in the two movies even remotely.

Comment: The point is, they tend to have a similar design.  It's only natural that some builders are going to add their own flair to it.  Stylistically, it makes sense to add some visual appeal to the film and make the staircase ornate.  As for any connection, they both take place on islands off of the NorthEast coast of the US, but the lighthouse on Shutter Island was only a small piece and was part of the hospital, whereas in The Lighthouse it was essentially the only building on the island, so there's no physical connection to the two.